# How would I set up mysql db hosting

Tags: mysql, web-hosting

I have a VPS and have set up vhosts so I cant host websites, im wanting to give each user the ability to create there own db within mysql, I have phpmyadmin installed so can login to that to view the db's, but I want the 'user' to be able to log in and only see there databases. what is the best way of dealing with this? thanks

Comment: If you have to ask, hosting is probably not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

If I remember well the user only sees the databases in phpmyadmin what he/she has rights.

Comment: So I guess create the db user at user creation then create a db for the user give permissions? the down side is if I gave them permission to create db's there would be not limit to how many dbs they could create

Comment: Create a separate database for every user and no other database for them. I think it's enough.

Comment: @Elgoog Does it really matter if they make a bunch of databases?

Comment: I guess not, but I dont want the system to be 'to' open to abuse

Answer (score 0):

Use phpmyadmin:
execute the GRANT query within the phpmyadmin query tab, 
repeat this process for other hosts you want to grant access for.

Edit the config.inc file for your controlled users granted access by the MYSQL GRANT query.
Essentially what you are doing is provided segmented access, and seperate Login and permissions for users you specify.
see the following link for more info:
[click this!](http://alandoyle.com/tutorials/configuring-phpmyadmin-for-multiple-users/)